# design jmeter test plan with grouped services with varying parameters

Tags: rest, jmeter

I am supposed to test some services like register, search, update ... for the functionalities.
I am a bit confused about how I should be designing my jmeter test plan.
I was thinking of the tes plan structure as

TestPlan
 -- ThreadGroup (service types)
    -- UDVs (Multiple as needed by services)
    -- Simple Controller - Register service
       -- register - Http request (with all parameters)
       -- register - Http request (with minimum parameters)
       -- register - Http request (different permutations of parameters)
       ...
    -- Simple Controller - Search service
       -- Search - Http request (with all parameters)
       -- Search - Http request (with minimum parameters)
       -- Search - Http request (different permutations of parameters)
       ...
...

My problem is by this design I am not able to vary the parameters for each request under same controller - e.g. all register requests will have same parameters username and password - which is not acceptable.

I am aware of multiple features in jmeter such as post processors, interleave controllers ... which I feel might help, but I am just not able to fit them into my design. Just wanted suggestions about how I should be going head for the test plan.

My main objective is to have a test plan for a demo which will show all the scenarios for different services. (hence need good grouping of the services)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UDV, you should use ***CSV Data Set Config***.

Prepare the CSV file with different parameters row wise e.g.  http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

hope this will help.

Comment: CSV is a good option. But the reason I want to avoid it is I will have to change the parameters in the csv file again and again. And another thing would be, it will not be easy to demo each and every scenario using a csv outside the jmeter and multiple csv would break the grouping. Of course changing the variables between the threads (which is not the case for me) CSV is best option. Its more about presentation than performance.Hope you understand what I am trying to point out.

Comment: I can understand that it is for presentation. what I cannot understand is why will you change parameters in CSV again and again. and also multiple CSV's its confusing? when your test plan above states something else.